# application_authenticaterequest does not fire when using Page.GetRouteUrl

Tags: asp.net

I'm converting some URLs from a web application using ASP.NET 4.0 friendly SEO Urls:

From
`<a href="profile.aspx" ></a>`

To
`<a href="<%= Page.GetRouteUrl("Profile", null) %>" ></a>`

The problem is before conversion when I try to hit profile.aspx it would fire the application_authenticaterequest but after conversion when I try to hit Page.GetRouteUrl it would not fire the application_authenticaterequest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It was a condition I had that was checking for request ending with .aspx and was doing a return.  The application_authenticaterequest is actually firing when using Page.GetRouteUrl